# Desencriptar una columna de base de datos Mysql con Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

estoy haciendo un crud de usuarios y sus datos los encripto con el enscriptador de Codeigniter 4

```
$this->encriptador = \Config\Services::encrypter();
$this->encriptador->encrypt($this->request->getPost("txtUsuario") ?? '');
```

En mi base de datos se guarda asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quiero realizar el select de los datos pero ya con los campos desencriptados, intente
usar el decrypt
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me da error 'Decrypting: authentication failed', la llave de encriptación si esta puesta.
Ahora que sucede si yo quisiera hacer una query desde mi base de datos pero ya con los nombres desencriptados, quise usar AES_DECRYPT junto con mi llave en los campos y no me desencripta, me bota null.
En conclusion quiero que me bote mis datos desencriptados y cuando yo quiera hacer un eco a esa consulta que tambien me de el codigo para yo asi poder pegar mi consulta dentro de mi mysql y que me aparezca ya los datos desencriptados

Comment: si el decrypt lo haces en php primero es el select luego decrypt. para armar un select asi y decirle q seleccione un campo tal tenes que encriptarlo en php enviar el select con el dato encryptado y recien cuando vuelve desencriptar el resto, sino la db no va a matchear nunca ( ni sabe q esta encryptado, para la db son bytes nomas)

Comment: creo que debes re evaluar la logica que estas aplicando ...